# Calculating average value in rows, between two dates, in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've reviewed lots of similar threads, but none have given me exactly what I'm looking for. My dataset contains aggregated data presented horizontally, rather than a series of vertical lists.

I have a dataset (weekly average login %) that looks like this:

```
Company Name  | 01/01/2018 | 07/01/2018 | 14/01/2018 | etc
Name1         |     3      |      2     |      5     |
Name2         |     2      |      1     |      2     |
```

What I'm hoping to get is the "What is the average weekly active logins for 'COMPANY NAME' between 'DATE1' and 'DATE2'.

I know I could write in the dates manually, but I'm hoping to check it for specific date periods across 5 years for 100+ rows. Something semi-scalable is ideal here.

Is there a way to do this? I feel stupid. This is likely trivial, but I'm a non-engineer and I've spent the last two days trying to figure this out!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Then, this looks like a reporting table.  Such a query would be much simpler on the base data.  Also, why would two rows have the same name?

Comment: Edited. Thanks Gordon! 

I don't have access to the base data. Our DB system (NoSQL) is a mess and it was difficult enough for the team to pull out this aggregated data a couple months ago.

Comment: This is an awful design. Don't expect easy solutions for problems like this when you have columns with names that are dates.

Comment: would you recommend trying to pivot the source data first?